# How to parse list containing decimal and datetime.datetime?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list coming from sql output which looks like this

```
[(Decimal('264'), datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 1, 0, 0)), (Decimal('445812776'), datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 1, 0, 0)), (Decimal('545942604'), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0))]
```

I want to plot graph using matplotlib with x as datetime and y as corresponding decimal.

For that i was trying to split this into two lists one containing decimals and other containing datetime, But i am not able to parse it i tried this

```
def convertTupletoString(s):
        return str(list(s)).strip('[]').strip('\'')
t=[]
d=[]
suppose list is x
  for i in list(x):
      s = convertTupletoString(i)
      x = s.find(",")
      traffic = float(s[:x])
      t.append(traffic)
      date = datetime(s[x+1:])
      d.append(date)

pyplot.plot(t,d)
```

I am getting cannot convert to float error , also not able to convert to datetime too.
Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datetime is **already** a datetime so try something like:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> Decimal = int
>>> x = [(Decimal('264'), datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 1, 0, 0)), (Decimal('445812776'), datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 1, 0, 0)), (Decimal('545942604'), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0))]
>>> x[0]
(264, datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 1, 0, 0))
>>> x[0][1]
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 1, 0, 0)
>>> d = [b for (a,b) in x]
>>> t = [a for (a,b) in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

check the type of the variable at first and then decide what to do...

```
if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime)
if isinstance(x, basestring)
```